# Is there a way to use C++/CLI managed Enums as array subscripts?

Tags: c++-cli

i have an enum declared as

```
enum class AccessLevel : int
{
    ReadOnly = 0,
    Excluded = 1,
    ReadWrite = 2,
};
```

and an Array declared as

```
static array<String^>^ _accessMap = gcnew array<String^> { "R", "X", "W" };
```

I want to do something like this:

```
AccessLevel^ access = access::ReadOnly;
String^ foo = _accessMap[access];
```

Comment: Could you please post the error that you are getting? You may need to supply an explicit cast. I would imagine that this would work in C# but in my short expereiance with C++/CLI I have found it to be "flaky." So try "String^ foo = _accessMap[(int)access];"

Comment: I get an error saying there is no implicit cast to int for AccessLevel.  If I say _accessMap[safe_cast<int>(access)], I get "error C2682: cannot use 'safe_cast' to convert from AccessLevel^ to int"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public enum struct AccessLevel
{
        ReadOnly = 0,
        Excluded = 1,
        ReadWrite = 2,
};

AccessLevel access = access::ReadOnly;
```

you might need to cast to an int

```
String^ foo = _accessMap[(int)access];
```